# How to Eradicate this error in C Program?

Tags: c, dll

This code is working fine in c++.I need the solution for C.

This is my sample.

```
 FileName:Mail.c
```

This is the declaration I made in the file mail.c

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
   typedef int (__cdecl *SetIpAddressFun)(char* , int  , int );
   typedef bool (__cdecl *SendMailFun)(char * , char *);
 #endif
```

I used this function pointers in the function called func() in the same file mail.c

```
 void func()
 {
     SendMailFun sendMailFuncPtr;
     SetIpAddressFun setIpAddressFuncPtr;
 }
```

**EDIT**

If i remove the #ifdef lines in the file mail.c then it is showing the following error.

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__cdecl'
 e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__cdecl'
 e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
 e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2165: 'left-side modifier' : cannot modify pointers to data
```

**ERROR**

List  of errors happened while compiling in c.

```
  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1615) : error   C2065: 'SendMailFun' : undeclared identifier

  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1615) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'sendMailFuncPtr'

  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1615) : error C2065: 'sendMailFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier
  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1616) : error C2065: 'SetIpAddressFun' : undeclared identifier
  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1616) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'setIpAddressFuncPtr'
  e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1616) : error C2065: 'setIpAddressFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier
   e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1625) : error C2065: 'setIpAddressFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier
   e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1625) : error C2065: 'SetIpAddressFun' : undeclared identifier
   e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1625) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1626) : error C2065: 'setIpAddressFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1626) : warning C4047: '!=' : 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1628) : warning C4013: 'setIpAddressFuncPtr' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1630) : error C2065: 'sendMailFuncPtr' : undeclared identifier
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1630) : error C2065: 'SendMailFun' : undeclared identifier
    e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(1630) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you declared the function

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   typedef int (__cdecl *SetIpAddressFun)(char* , int  , int );
   typedef bool (__cdecl *SendMailFun)(char * , char *);
 #endif
```

you do it conditionally only for **__cplusplus** which is typically not defined when compiling C files

**EDIT**

I think your second problem is to do with the presence of **bool** which to my knowledge is not  **C** keyword. Considering replacing it with an **int**

Answer (score 1):

The `#ifdef __cplusplus` means that bit of code will only be complied when using a C++ compiler.

It's the bit that defines the function pointer type `SendMailFun`, so the compiler errors are complaining that `SendMailFun` and `SendMailFun` don’t exist.

You could start by removing the lines

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

and

```
#endif
```

Comment: Douglas: If I remove the lines then it is showing the following error.error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__cdecl'
e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__cdecl'
e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
e:\projects\avg\apps\ezcepanel i.7 - pcpanel from vss\ccode\alarms.c(138) : error C2165: 'left-side modifier' : cannot modify pointers to data

Comment: Douglas: If you are not able to visualize this comment.Then see my Edit part in the Question itself

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you're using Visual Studio on Windows, which I don't really know enough about to be able to help further…
You could try removing the __cdecl bit, but that's probably not the issue and might cause others.

Comment: Douglas:+1 for your approach.Thanks for your reply.